# How to add a column as a result of date function in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, date, plsql, insert

I have a SQL query which selects only four columns from a table and adds to it another column which will be the result of a function. The function is to produce dates, it takes a number as parameter and adds it to SYSDATE to produce future days:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION future(p_day NUMBER)
RETURN DATE
IS
--
v_date DATE;
--
BEGIN
--
v_date := SYSDATE + p_day;
RETURN v_date;
--
END;
```

The feature of the SQL column selections are:

1. first three columns are unique combination and this this is done by grouping by
      SELECT a, b, c FROM table GROUP BY a, b, c;
2. the fourth column (h) is numeric values for ease I just say 1-10 
      so currently in the original table each unique combination of a, b, c has 1 to 10
      assigned:

```
 -+----+----+----+----+-
  | a  |  b |  c | h  |  <----Column names
 -+----+----+----+----+-
  | a1 | b1 | c1 |  1 |
 -+----+----+----+----+-
  | a1 | b1 | c1 |  2 |
 -+----+----+----+----+-
  | a1 | b1 | c1 |  3 |
 -+----+----+----+----+-
  | a1 | b1 | c1 |  4 |
 -+----+----+----+----+-
    :    :     :    :
    :    :     :    :
 -+----+----+----+----+-
  | a1 | b1 | c1 |  9 |
 -+----+----+----+----+-
  | a1 | b1 | c1 | 10 |
 -+----+----+----+----+-
  | a1 | b1 | c2 |  1 |
 -+----+----+----+----+-
  | a1 | b1 | c2 |  2 |
 -+----+----+----+----+-
    :    :     :    :
    :    :     :    :
```

so now I have to add dates between column c and h by using my function(or any other methods that will do the same job) which will be 7 days in the future and the column should change so that for each day there is a unique combination and 10 numeric values. Thant means if there are 50 a, b, c combination the rows of the query will be 50*7*10 = 3500. now I don't know how to insert the seven days. I thought about the FOR i IN 1..7 LOOP but still can't figure it out.
Please give me some advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5477f9/19).
This is a sample Query Example.

```
select Temp.*,to_char(adate,'dd/MM/yyyy') d from Temp,
(
SELECT (SYSDATE + ROWNUM -1) adate
  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 7
) T
order by Temp.A,Temp.B,Temp.C,Temp.h,T.adate
```

Comment: yes, the result is exactly what was required,thank you, but is there any general way of producing of date, for instance, if I am asked to produce the result for next 100 days then I have to type 100 time of sysdate + i...?

Comment: @DilshatAbduwalli Now check my Ans again. I have changed as per Detail given.